# fill missing data by rule for each consecutive NaN-block

Tags: python, pandas

I'm fairly new to python and pandas.

Several sensors write data to a database at varying intervals, usually many times per minute.

I read this data into a pandas dataframe, resample it to 1 minute and aggregate the values. There are minutes without a data point in col_a and col_b, so the resampled dataframe contains NaNs in these columns. The resampled dataframe looks like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

d = {'tstamptz': [  '2022-08-09 10:30:00+00:02',
                    '2022-08-09 10:30:01+00:02',
                    '2022-08-09 10:30:02+00:02',
                    '2022-08-09 10:30:03+00:02',
                    '2022-08-09 10:30:04+00:02',
                    '2022-08-09 10:30:05+00:02',
                    '2022-08-09 10:30:06+00:02',
                    '2022-08-09 10:30:07+00:02',
                    '2022-08-09 10:30:08+00:02',
                    '2022-08-09 10:30:09+00:02',
                    '2022-08-09 10:30:10+00:02'],
     'col_a': [413.8, 409.6, np.nan, np.nan, 409.6, 405.1, 417.3, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 426.4],
     'col_b': [409.6, 407.9, np.nan, np.nan, 405.1, 417.3, 431.4, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 419.9],
     'col_c': [5.1, 5.1, 5.0, 5.0, 5.0, 5.0, 4.9, 4.9, 5.0, 5.0, 5.1]}

df = pd.DataFrame(d)
df.set_index('tstamptz', inplace=True)
```

I fill the missing data as follows:

- The last available value of col_b goes into col_a of the first nan row.
- The first available value after the NaN rows of col_a goes into col_b of the first NaN row.
- The values are propagated for all further, consecutive NaN rows: col_b -> col_a

This must be done for all consecutive NaN rows, so that this process is restarted as soon as a non-NaN row follows.

This is my current solution to do this:

```
result = df.copy()
last_index_position = result.index.get_loc(result.index[-1])

# While there are any NaN rows
while result[['col_a','col_b']].isnull().values.any():

    # Get index position of first NaN row
   first_nan = list(np.where(result[['col_a','col_b']].isna()))[0][0]
   
   try:
      # Check, up to which index position it contains consecutive NaN rows
      next_nonan_index = result.index.get_loc(
                              result[['col_a','col_b']].iloc[first_nan:].first_valid_index()
                         )
   # Catch the KeyError, if there is no valid index left in dataframe (last index is NaN)
   except KeyError:
      next_nonan_index = last_index_position + 1 # add 1 to include last index in ffill method

   # Make sure, that there's a non-NaN row in front of the NaN row(s)
   # If the row on position 0 is NaN, take 0 instead of -1
   if first_nan - 1 >= 0:
      fillblock_start = first_nan -1
   else:
      fillblock_start = 0
   
   # Fill the first NaN row
   result['col_a'].iloc[fillblock_start:next_nonan_index].fillna(
      df['col_b'].ffill(), limit = 1, inplace = True)
   result['col_b'].iloc[fillblock_start:next_nonan_index].fillna(
      df['col_a'].bfill(), limit = 1, inplace = True)
   

   # Fill the rest of the rows
   result['col_a'].iloc[fillblock_start:next_nonan_index].fillna(
      result['col_b'].ffill(), inplace = True)   
   result['col_b'].iloc[fillblock_start:next_nonan_index].fillna(
      result['col_b'].ffill(), inplace = True)
```

This works as expected, but is terribly awkward.

**Question:**
How can I let pandas do this in a cleaner and probably faster way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following in this sequence:

1. [fill](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html) `NaN`s in `col_a` with [shifted](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html?highlight=shift#pandas.Series.shift) `col_b` (this only replaces the first `NaN` in each group)
2. [backfill](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.backfill.html) the remaining `NaN`s in `col_a`
3. fill `NaN`s in `col_b` with backshifted `col_a` (this only replaces the first `NaN` in each group)
4. [forward fill](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.ffill.html) the remaining `NaN`s in `col_b`

```py
result = df.copy()
result.col_a = result.col_a.fillna(result.col_b.shift()).backfill()
result.col_b = result.col_b.fillna(result.col_a.shift(-1)).ffill()
```

Result:

```
                           col_a  col_b  col_c
tstamptz                                      
2022-08-09 10:30:00+00:02  413.8  409.6    5.1
2022-08-09 10:30:01+00:02  409.6  407.9    5.1
2022-08-09 10:30:02+00:02  407.9  409.6    5.0
2022-08-09 10:30:03+00:02  409.6  409.6    5.0
2022-08-09 10:30:04+00:02  409.6  405.1    5.0
2022-08-09 10:30:05+00:02  405.1  417.3    5.0
2022-08-09 10:30:06+00:02  417.3  431.4    4.9
2022-08-09 10:30:07+00:02  431.4  426.4    4.9
2022-08-09 10:30:08+00:02  426.4  426.4    5.0
2022-08-09 10:30:09+00:02  426.4  426.4    5.0
2022-08-09 10:30:10+00:02  426.4  419.9    5.1
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for, thank you so much! It also takes half the time :). If the last row and at least one row before has NaN values, col_a is not filled to the last row, so I added this after your two lines: `result.col_a = result.col_a.fillna(result.col_a).ffill()`